# Reducing Flutter project sizes

Tags: flutter, dart

My development folder has about 40 Flutter projects in it and they are taking up 23GB worth of disk space.

In my Node.js projects I can delete all `node_modules` folders to free up space on archived projects, simply typing `npm install` in the project folder if I ever need to run it again.

What similar steps can be taken to reduce the disk space taken up by old Flutter projects?

Answer (score 5):

This brought my folder size from 23GB to 8.5GB after running this

`find . -name "pubspec.yaml" -execdir flutter clean \;`

Comment: how to do this in windows 10

Comment: this will pretty much solve the problem for you, just make sure to update your windows path: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows